# How to handle the reload when using react-router and webpack server

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I am using react-router and debug my code in webpack hot server, when I tried to reload the page which is not in index path, it came to empty without any errors. I checked the page elements and found the scripts are not included.

The reason is that my index.html is a template and generated with HtmlWebpackPlugin finally, as below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I send all requests to this index.html in my express server:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html'));
});
```

How can I solve this problem without manually including scripts in the index.html file?

Comment: `HtmlWebpackPlugin()` should include the script tag with the generated `index.html` file. Please update the question with webpack config file